# JAVA List / Read directory from url

Tags: java, web-services, url, directory

I have a URL which can be accessed from  the server, It has a Lot of XML, logs files which get updated on a regular basis and hence I need to keep tap for the user to see

Is is possible that I can get the names of those files and possibly even display the content in a view for the user to see?

I tries this but it didnt work at all.

note I cant access the machine any other way, just the URL

```
 String path = request.getContextPath();
path += DOWNLOADS;
URL url = null;
String server = request.getServerName();
try {
    url = new URL("https", server, request.getLocalPort(), path);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if (url != null) {
    String externalForm = url.toExternalForm();
    File directory = new File(externalForm);
    String[] files = directory.list();
    for (String file : files) {
        ;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Now tell us what doesn't work. How is it behaving differently than your expectation?

Comment: if you dont want to answer thats fine, you cannot judge

Comment: He is not judging.  We cannot help you unless we know what it's doing and/or not doing.  But, I can tell you the above doesn't do anything.  For start, you open a URL, do nothing of sustenance with it, then use it to open a File, then do nothing of sustenance with that either.  At some point, you need to open an InputStream and read the file on the remote system.